LaTeX OverLeaf lines overlap in the code editor
I have a document in LaTeX on Overleaf and I'm struggling a little bit with the code editor. Namely, two lines in the code editor seem to be overlapping and I can't separate them. I also can not edit the 'covered' line. I have attached some screenshots because I feel like they would be a better explanation.
Please note that even if I delete the line itself, it doesn't help because the issue shifts to cover another line. Additionally, if I directly copy paste the code into a new document, the same issue reappears.



so it just affects the line numbers in wrapped lines, not the actual text? what happens if you use a different browser?

@DavidCarlisle No. Line 150 isn't visible at all. Compare with the code shown in the top image - there's a line missing in the second which seems to be 'covered' by the next.

I think you should ask it to Overleaf Help Desk, click on "Help" --> "Contact Us." They usually reply very promptly.

Sounds good, I thought I accidentally triggered it with a random hotkey, but I will contact the help desk!
